# Инициализация пользователя при входе в сетевую игру (Android, Java)

Tags: разработка-игр, android, java

Всем привет! Делаю сетевую карточную игру для Андроида. Используется облачный сервер. 
Принцип работы приложения:
Пользователь №1, подключаясь к серверу, вбивает свое имя. Затем он попадает на экран, где ему предлагается создать игровую комнату. Он ее создает и переносится на игровой экран.
Пользователь №2 также вбивает ник, подключается к серверу, а на следующем экране кроме возможности создать свою комнату у него есть возможность зайти в комнату, которую создал Пользователь №1. Он заходит в нее и так же переносится на игровой экран.
Вопрос:
Как мне "разделить" этих пользователей в игре? Один должен войти в нее как Игрок А, другой - как Игрок Б. По логике - при нажатии на кнопку "Создать комнату" пользователь должен инициализироваться как Игрок А, а при нажатии на кнопку "Войти в комнату [уже созданную]" - как Игрок Б.
Сейчас вообще войти в комнату как игроку не получается - только как зрителю. То есть на эмуляторе комната создается, я туда попадаю, но действий никаких совершать не могу.
Код пока никакой не выкладываю - боюсь еще сильнее все запутать.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Пользователь входит в комнату со своим ником, этот ник и отображается. Если ник пользователся — «Игрок А», он должен везде отображаться как «Игрок А». Если ник пользователся — «Rm1», он должен везде отображаться как «Rm1».

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так: к имени игрока прибавьте метку [Server], но не показывайте её самому игроку, а у клиента сделайте фильтрацию, чтобы показывались в списке комнат только те игроки, которые имеют метку [Server]

Comment: VladD, проблема в том, что пользователь в комнату вообще без ника входит. Вот я и спрашиваю, как мне ему "на хвост" ник прилепить. А в довесок еще добавить ему, что он или Игрок А (кто создал комнату) или игрок Б (кто вошел в комнату) - это уже не ники, а так скажем, программные обозначения игроков, чтобы их разделить.
SuperCreeper, формально в созданной комнате вообще никого нет. В этом и проблема. Так что метка здесь не поможет. Игрок создает в комнату, но входит в нее как зритель. Пока не пойму почему.